# Explanation of a css code line

Tags: css, html

The code is:

```
background: url(images/cs.jpg) no-repeat 0cm 0.2cm;
```

I am unsure what is 0cm 0.2cm standing for. Could anyone please explain me what does it do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `background-position` value

```
background-position: left top;
background-position: 0cm 0.2cm;
```

Comment: Thank you for help